# half page's width background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a menu which is divided by 50% width. 
this is what i've been trying so far: 
http://jsbin.com/gobacewovu/1 

so, as you can see, my problem is that the "search" text is invisible. I noticed this problem and created another page, using a "menu" class. 
http://jsbin.com/melekitata/1

the problem is now bigger. I was even looking for a solution in this site but I have not found a solution yet, though.

does anyone can help me with that, I'm seriously stuck. 
thanks.

Comment: Do you need `.menu` to be 50% width of the page? OR `#search` 50% + `#look` 50% of the page?

Answer (score 1):

It is because `#look` has fixed position, you would need to give `#search` `position: relative; z-index: 1;` to place it higher up the stacking order.

**CSS**

```
#search {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to achieve with this layout however but if you give me some more info I can help you.

Comment: Was about to post an answer and realised you'd beaten me too it, +1

Comment: I haven't understood yet how this code supposed to affect my code. That's what I have finally reached: [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/yerizepoda/1/)

BTW I want to get the page parted into to parts which are depended on their width. Left and right side, both of them are 50% width.